# Console Ignoring Inputs

Tags: java

I've created a program using Scanner to take in a number from the user and save it to 'a' when it is an integer from 1 to 100. Please see the Java file below:

```
public class Parity_Check {
  private static Scanner sc;

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int a, b;
    System.out.print("Enter a number     between 1 and 100: ");

    while(true) {
      b = 0;
      if(!sc.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.print("That isn't an integer! Try again: "); 
        sc.next();
      }
      else{
        b = sc.nextInt();
        if(b < 1 || b > 100) {
          System.out.print("That integer isn't between 1 and 100! Try again: "); 
          sc.next();
        }
        else{
          a = b; 
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    System.out.print("The number is: "+a+".");
  }
}
```

The problem I’m having is as follows:
After the program returns “That integer isn't between 1 and 100! Try again: ,“ it waits for two inputs from the user (rather than the one it should) - the first of which is completely ignored!
Here’s the console session I ran to illustrate the problem:

```
"Enter a number between 1 and 100: 2.5
That isn't an integer! Try again: 101
That integer isn't between 1 and 100! Try again: Apple.
42
The number is: 42.”
```

As you can see it didn't even pay attention to the input `"Apple".`  I’m completely lost as to why this doesn’t work as it should, like so:

```
"Enter a number between 1 and 100: 2.5
That isn't an integer! Try again: 101
That integer isn't between 1 and 100! Try again: Apple.
That isn't an integer! Try again: 42
The number is: 42.”
```

I'm very new to Java so an answer that's well explained would be a Godsend; I'm more interested in why it doesn't work than how to fix it because hopefully I'll be able to learn.

I'm using the latest version of Eclipse 64-bit, by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have already removed an int from the stream, so you have to remove anything more. Take out the call to sc.next():

```
    b = sc.nextInt();
    if(b < 1 || b > 100) {
      System.out.print("That integer isn't between 1 and 100! Try again: "); 
      // sc.next(); remove this
    }
```

Notice how this is different from the situation with the earlier if-statement: if the user types in something that's not a number you *must* remove it from the stream by calling next() because  nothing else would remove it otherwise. Here the call to nextInt already removes input from the stream.

Comment: Ah, so I remove the integer from the stream when I set b to it? Perfect answer, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The sc.next() in your if statement is not needed and makes your code skip over the next input from the user. The code snippet below works correctly as you intended.

```
private static Scanner sc;

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int a, b;
    System.out.println("Enter a number     between 1 and 100: ");

    while(true) {
        b = 0;
        if(!sc.hasNextInt()) {
            System.out.println("That isn't an integer! Try again: ");
            sc.next(); 
        }
        else {
            b = sc.nextInt();
        }
        if(b < 1 || b > 100) {
            System.out.println("That integer isn't between 1 and 100! Try again: "); 
        }
        else {
            a = b; 
            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The number is: "+a+".");
    return;
}
```

Comment: I think you may have removed the wrong "sc.next();" but I worked it out. =P Thank you very much!

Comment: I got there in the end haha

Answer (score 0):

try with below main it will work

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

```
sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int a, b;
System.out.print("Enter a number     between 1 and 100: ");

while(true) {
  b = 0;
  if(!sc.hasNextInt()) {
    System.out.print("That isn't an integer! Try again: "); 
    sc.next();
  }
  else{
    b = sc.nextInt();
    if(b < 1 || b > 100) {
      System.out.print("That integer isn't between 1 and 100! Try again: "); 
    }
    else{
      a = b; 
      break;
    }
  }
}
System.out.print("The number is: "+a+".");
```

}